How to achieve more accurate types?
What happens in the following function, even though the types are explicitly declared, the final type is not inferred as expected?
type ClampRangeReturnType<L extends number | undefined | null, U extends number | undefined | null, Min extends number | undefined | null, Max extends number | undefined | null> = [
  Min extends number ? number : L extends number ? number : undefined,
  Max extends number ? number : U extends number ? number : undefined
]

export const clampRange = <L extends number | undefined | null, U extends number | undefined | null, Min extends number | undefined | null, Max extends number | undefined | null>(
  values: {
    lower?: L,
    upper?: U,
  } = {},
  limits: {
    minAllowed?: Min,
    maxAllowed?: Max,
  } = {}): ClampRangeReturnType<L, U, Min, Max> => {
  const clampedRange = []

  const { lower, upper } = values
  const { minAllowed, maxAllowed } = limits

  clampedRange[0] = typeof lower === "number" ? typeof minAllowed === "number" && minAllowed > lower ? minAllowed : lower : undefined
  clampedRange[1] = typeof upper === "number" ? typeof maxAllowed === "number" && maxAllowed > upper ? maxAllowed : upper : undefined

  return clampedRange as ClampRangeReturnType<L, U, Min, Max>
}

const [yearFrom, yearTo] = clampRange({lower: 2010})
// `yearFrom` is `number | undefined` here.

const [yearFrom, yearTo] = clampRange({lower: _dataParsed?.yearFrom})
// But, `yearFrom` is also `number` here, while `_dataParsed?.yearFrom` is a possible `undefined`.

yearFrom should inferred as undefined or number | undefined at least, while it is annotated as number.

In the case of clampRange({lower: 2010}) I'm getting yearFrom type as number. In the first case, _dataParsed is not defined so it's impossible to tell what you expected. Playground: https://tsplay.dev/mZRkam

Thanks for your tip, I edited the question. @shadowusr

Please [edit] this code to be a [mre] with a very clear description of what you mean and what you're looking for. I don't see anything "annotated" as number anywhere, and the types in your comments don't match up to what I'm seeing. You say "it's number | undefined" but I see number. And _dataParsed is not declared, so I just get any there. And of course you have multiple variables named yearFrom and yearTo.  Ideally we can take your code, copy it into our own IDEs, and immediately see the issue and get to work on it. Right now it's not clear.

The issue arises because the conditional types in ClampRangeReturnType do not distribute over union types like number | undefined. This causes the type inference to be less precise than expected.
Fix this by modifying the ClampRangeReturnType to use distributive conditional types. This ensures that the conditional types are applied to each member of the union separately.
type ClampRangeReturnType<
  L extends number | undefined | null,
  U extends number | undefined | null,
  Min extends number | undefined | null,
  Max extends number | undefined | null
> = [
  Min extends number
    ? number
    : L extends number
    ? number
    : undefined,
  Max extends number
    ? number
    : U extends number
    ? number
    : undefined
];

To make it distributive, we need to adjust it:
type ClampRangeReturnType<
  L extends number | undefined | null,
  U extends number | undefined | null,
  Min extends number | undefined | null,
  Max extends number | undefined | null
> = [
  L extends infer T ? (
    T extends number
      ? Min extends number
        ? number
        : T
      : undefined
  ) : undefined,
  U extends infer T ? (
    T extends number
      ? Max extends number
        ? number
        : T
      : undefined
  ) : undefined
];

Remove the type assertion in the function:
return clampedRange; // remove type assertion


Can you lead me to some environment you tested the suggestion, if you did?  @Kozydot
